# Range class in ruby source code?

Tags: ruby

Where can I find methods of `Range` class in Ruby's source code. I am particularly looking for `Range#last` method. Ruby -v MRI 1.9.2

Comment: Have you looked at the C source at all?

Comment: nope. In it where can i find it?

Comment: @BhushanLodha: note your question. Where can I ... in Ruby's source code. If you haven't looked at the source, how were you expecting to find it? Unless you've made a typo and you're just looking for the reference for ruby's Range class. Is that the case?

Comment: @LiorCohen no I was actually looking for source code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can find the Ruby source here

https://github.com/ruby/ruby/

It has a `range.c` in its root directory.

and for the `Range#last` implementation in source, I think it is here:

https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/trunk/range.c#L602

http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Range.html#method-i-last

Answer (score 2):

Personally, I very much prefer looking at [Rubinius](http://Rubini.us/)'s [source code](https://GitHub.Com/Rubinius/Rubinius/), because I find it *much more* readable than YARV's. The method you are looking for is in [kernel/common/range.rb](https://GitHub.Com/Rubinius/Rubinius/blob/b9247312c0f92e1e881c30a8f6a2e826c7a8101d/kernel/common/range.rb#L126-127), and it is simply a getter for the `@end` instance variable:

```
attr_reader :end
alias_method :last, :end
```

The `@end` instance variable is set in the [`initialize` method](https://GitHub.Com/Rubinius/Rubinius/blob/b9247312c0f92e1e881c30a8f6a2e826c7a8101d/kernel/common/range.rb#L6-20). In other words: the `last` method simply always returns the value that you passed to `Range.new`.

Note that, in this case, Rubinius's implementation conforms to the Ruby 1.8 language specification and hasn't been updated to the Ruby 1.9 specification yet, which has an optional `count` parameter.